# Using virtualenv to install different versions of same package

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Since I have Django 1.1x on my Debian setup - how can I use `virtualenv` or similar and not have it mess up my system's default django version which in turn would break all my sites?

Detailed instructions or a great tutorial link would very much be appreciated - please don't offer vague advice since I'm still a noob.

Currently I store all my django projects in `~/django-sites` and I am using Apache2 + mod_wsgi to deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have easy_install, or better yet `pip` installed, should be as easy as:

1. `easy_install/pip install virtualenv`
2. `mkdir django1.2`
3. `virtualenv django1.2`

This will put the python binary in a `bin` folder inside the `django1.2` folder. Just use that python binary, and you've got a nice little self-contained environment. You can then install easy_install/pip into *that* environment, and then install django 1.2 as well, and hack away.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide absolute paths of where you would typically install these? `~/`?

Comment: well, usually what I do is this:

1. `sudo python -c "$(curl -s http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py)"`
2. sudo easy_install pip
3. sudo pip install virtualenv

Then you have `virtualenv` in your path. Proceed from there. You can put the virtual environment anywhere on your filesystem.

Comment: I know you can put it anywhere, but for example if you have `DocumentRoot` in your apache2 pointing to /var/www/html by default that's probably not a good place.

Comment: You don't have to put it in there. You can put it wherever you want, and then just use an `Alias` directive in your httpd.conf to serve the django app in a subfolder. That's how I do it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using mod_wsgi, make sure you read:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments